# self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE does not work on one UIViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, hidden

In my app I have at least a dozen `UIViewController`, some of them show navigation bar, some of them don't.  Everything works fine on all but one controllers.

I navigate to this screen from another one that does not have the nav bar shown. On this one, I need the nav bar shown, so in my `viewWillAppear` I have this code:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

When I step through the code with a debugger, I go through this line, however it's just ignored and the nav bar is not shown.  This appears to be a problem on both the simulator and an actual device (iPhone 4S with iOS 5.1.1).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, I hit another one of those Apple "just bloody do it" things.

In addition to having that line in the `viewWillAppear` method, I added this to `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

Now it work as I want it.  Interestingly, if I remove either of the two lines, it doesn't work; it only works with both lines in place.

Whatever, it works now.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. It turns out the viewcontroller i was departing from had     `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` in it's `viewWillDisappear` method, which caused it to animate in on transition regardless of the content in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 2):

That line would change the visibility of the *toolbar*, not the *navigation bar*.

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course.  That was a copy/paste from the wrong line in the file.  I do have `setNavigationBarHidden:NO`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have your method like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

so move the [super ...] line up, change it to this 
(both in your RootViewController and target view controller):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

this works for me.